# Network Connected Printer not available in ASP.Net Application

Tags: asp.net, iis, printing, impersonation

I have an ASP.Net 4.0 web application running on IIS 7.5, I can get the list of installed printers using `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` command and assign each report in the application to any printer listed above!

There might be some **Network Connected Printers** on the server all set with **full privilege** to the application's user account, everything works perfect until the application's user account logs off the windows, at this point `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` returns only local printers, no Network Connected Printers are listed!

I've tried to impersonate the ASP.Net process to the user with access to Network Printers in following ways, yet no success:

- I configured the application pool `Process Model` to run as a
  specific user identity.
- I impersonated the Application's identity to specific user in
  Web.Config:

  `<identity impersonate="true" userName="user" password="pass"/>`
- And finally implemented impersonation in code using `advapi32.dll` API

In all of the methods above, the `WindowsIdentity` returns the true username when printing:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

But it looks like that impersonation is not the issue here, the moment the user logs off, all Network Connected Printers are gone!

Does anybody know how to resolve this? Is there any way to access Network Connected Printers even when the user is not logged in?

Comment: We're having the same issue... Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network Connected Printers, Shared Folders and Map Drives are only accessible when user logs into the OS, they are barely a shortcut to some network resources, all disconnected and are inaccessible when the corresponding user logs off!

Using `System.Printing.PrintServer` and the `GetPrintQueues` method, you can get the collection of print queues that the print server hosts:

`PrintServerUNCName` is the [UNC name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#UNC_in_Windows) of the corresponding server, as in `\\MyServerName`

```
var printers = new PrintServer("PrintServerUNCName").GetPrintQueues()
    .Where(t =>
    {
        try { return t.IsShared && !t.IsNotAvailable; }
        catch { return false; }
    })
    .Select(t => t.FullName)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

try following links that might help. You have to add printer on your server by name and access the printer using the name rather UNC.

[Printing from ASP.NET to a network printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729153/printing-from-asp-net-to-a-network-printer)